# How create custom action button on sharepoint online command bar without spfx?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I'm creating a provider hosted add-in for sharepoint online and i want to create button or, better if possible, a dropdown button in the command bar, somthing like this:

[image]

maybe this question has been asked many times but i can't find any clear answer.

So far i could create buttons inside the context menu of the items creating custom actions with visual studio.

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="2bd189ad-3561-405e-815e-39f1a7fa1548.MenuItemCustomAction2"
                RegistrationType="List"
                RegistrationId="101"
                Location="EditControlBlock"
                Sequence="10001"
                Title="Invoke &apos;MenuItemCustomAction2&apos; action">
    <!-- 
    Update the Url below to the page you want the custom action to use.
    Start the URL with the token ~remoteAppUrl if the page is in the
    associated web project, use ~appWebUrl if page is in the app project.
    -->
    <UrlAction Url="~remoteAppUrl/WebForm1.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPListItemId={ItemId}&amp;SPListId={ListId}" />
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

but i can't find a similar one for the command bar. I'm not using sfpx because, as far as i understand, it is just for sharepoint hosted applications.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for the idea. I created a ribbon button with visual studio, this is how the xml codes looks if anyone wants in the future.

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="9b50e988-bfdd-4415-a883-4e645c642d49.RibbonCustomAction1"
                RegistrationType="ContentType"
                RegistrationId="0x0101"
                Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
                Sequence="10001"
                Title="Invoke RibbonCustomAction action">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <!-- 
      Update the UI definitions below with the controls and the command actions
      that you want to enable for the custom action.
      -->
        <CommandUIDefinitions>
            <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Tabs._children">
                <Tab Id="Custom Tab" Title="Custom Tab" Description="Custom Tab">
                    <Scaling Id="Custom Tab.Scaling">
                        <MaxSize Id="Custom Group.Scaling.MaxSize" GroupId="Custom Group" Size="TwoLarge" />
                        <MaxSize Id="Custom Group 2.Scaling.MaxSize" GroupId="Custom Group 2" Size="OneLarge" />
                        <Scale Id="Custom Group.Scaling.Scale" GroupId="Custom Group" Size="TwoLarge" />
                        <Scale Id="Custom Group 2.Scaling.Scale" GroupId="Custom Group 2" Size="OneLarge" />
                    </Scaling>
                    <Groups Id="Custom Tab.Groups">
                        <Group Id="Custom Group 2" Title="Custom Group 2" Description="Custom Group 2" Sequence="7888" Template="Ribbon.Templates.OneLarge">
                            <Controls Id="Custom Group 2.Controls">
                                <Button Id="CustomButton3" LabelText="Custom Button 3" Image16by16="/_layouts/15/images/attach16.png" Image32by32="/_layouts/15/images/attach16.png" ToolTipTitle="Custom Button 3" ToolTipDescription="Custom Button 3" Command="CustomButton3.Command" TemplateAlias="c3" />
                            </Controls>
                        </Group>
                        <Group Id="Custom Group" Title="Custom Group 1" Description="Custom Group 1" Sequence="10000" Template="Ribbon.Templates.TwoLarge">
                            <Controls Id="Custom Group 1.Controls">
                                <Button Id="CustomButton1" LabelText="Custom Button 1" Image16by16="/_layouts/15/images/itslidelibrary.png" Image32by32="/_layouts/15/images/itslidelibrary.png" ToolTipTitle="Custom Button 1" ToolTipDescription="Custom Button 1" Command="CustomButton1.Command" TemplateAlias="c1" />
                                <Button Id="CustomButton2" LabelText="Custom Button 2" Image16by16="/_layouts/15/images/dldsln16.png" Image32by32="/_layouts/15/images/dldsln16.png" ToolTipTitle="Custom Button 2" ToolTipDescription="Custom Button 2" Command="CustomButton2.Command" TemplateAlias="c2" />
                            </Controls>
                        </Group>
                    </Groups>
                </Tab>
            </CommandUIDefinition>
            <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
                <GroupTemplate Id="Ribbon.Templates.TwoLarge">
                    <Layout Title="TwoLarge" LayoutTitle="TwoLarge">
                        <Section Alignment="Top" Type="OneRow">
                            <Row>
                                <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="c1" />
                                <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="c2" />
                            </Row>
                        </Section>
                    </Layout>
                </GroupTemplate>
            </CommandUIDefinition>
            <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
                <GroupTemplate Id="Ribbon.Templates.OneLarge">
                    <Layout Title="OneLarge" LayoutTitle="OneLarge">
                        <Section Alignment="Top" Type="OneRow">
                            <Row>
                                <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="c3" />
                            </Row>
                        </Section>
                    </Layout>
                </GroupTemplate>
            </CommandUIDefinition>
        </CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIHandlers>
            <CommandUIHandler Command="CustomButton1.Command" CommandAction="https://contoso.azurewebsites.net/pages/index.aspx" />
            <CommandUIHandler Command="CustomButton2.Command" CommandAction="http://www.bing.com" />
            <CommandUIHandler Command="CustomButton3.Command" CommandAction="https://developer.microsoft.com/sharepoint" />
        </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension >
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Create custom action buttons  to SharePoint List using SharePoint Designer 2013**

`Note: This only works for classic view lists.`

- 1.Download the print icon and upload it to Site Assets Library

[image]

- 2.Open your list in SharePoint Designer 2013
- 3.Click on "**Display Form Ribbon**" on "**Custom Action**" dropdown menu

[image]

- 4.Name it "Print Item" and Set “Navigate to URL:” to

  **javascript:window.print()**
- 5.Browse for the button image URL (I used **32×32**) and select the **print.png** image you added to **Site Assets Library**

[image]

- 6.Change “**Manage**” in Ribbon Location to “**Actions**” and click **OK**

  **Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Actions.Controls._children**

[image]