# How to add button to SharePoint 2013 ribbon using JavaScript

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, javascript, document-library, custom-actions

Is it possible to use JavaScript to dynamically add a custom button to the ribbon?

I want to add a button next to the upload document button in a document library.

Any ideas or code how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the hashtag *2013* I guess your question is for Sharepoint 2013?

Back in time I created a JS library to do what you're looking for: https://github.com/Aymkdn/RibbonPlus

Comment: This works most of the time. Sometimes the button is not added. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I replied to your issue on Github.

Answer (score 2):

You can add button to the ribbon using **Custom Actions**.

Check below references for more information & code:

1. [Create Ribbon Custom Action Using JavaScript Object Model In SharePoint 2016 And Office 365](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-ribbon-custom-action-using-javascript-object-model-in-sharepoint-2016-and/)
2. [Create custom actions to deploy with SharePoint Add-ins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/Create-custom-actions-to-deploy-with-SharePoint-Add-ins) - Documentation
3. [How create custom action button on sharepoint online command bar without spfx?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/289668/how-create-custom-action-button-on-sharepoint-online-command-bar-without-spfx)